# Политика конфиденциальности для android приложения (Privacy policy)

Tags: android, google-play, документация, privacy

Пришло письмо от **Google**:

> Hi developers at Starikov Mark,
>
> After review, (название приложения), (пакет приложения),
>   has been removed from Google Play due to a policy violation. This app
>   won’t be available to users until you submit a compliant update.
>
> Issue: Violation of Usage of Android Advertising ID policy and section
>   4.8 of the Developer Distribution Agreement
>
> Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when
>   the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information.
>   We’ve identified that your app collects and transmits the Android
>   advertising identifier, which is subject to a privacy policy
>   requirement. If your app collects the Android advertising ID, you must
>   provide a valid privacy policy in both the designated field in the
>   Play Console, and from within the app.
>
> Next steps: Submit your app for another review
>
> Read through the Usage of Android Advertising ID and User Data
>   policies, as well as the Developer Distribution Agreement, and make
>   appropriate changes to your app. If you decide to collect sensitive
>   user information, be sure to abide by the above policies, and include
>   a link to a valid privacy policy on your app's store listing page and
>   within your app.  Make sure that your app is compliant with all other
>   Developer Program Policies. Additional enforcement could occur if
>   there are further policy violations. Sign in to your Play Console and
>   submit the update to your app. Alternatively, you may opt-out of this
>   requirement by removing any requests for sensitive permissions or user
>   data.
>
> If approved, your app will again be available with all installs,
>   ratings, and reviews intact.
>
> If you’ve reviewed the policy and feel this removal may have been in
>   error, please reach out to our policy support team. One of my
>   colleagues will get back to you within 2 business days.
>
> Thanks for helping us provide a clear and transparent experience for
>   Google Play users.
>
> Regards,
>
> Jaime
>
> The Google Play Team

Они проверили мое приложение, опубликованное в **Google Play**, и обнаружили то, что я использую *ID рекламных баннеров*, но не предоставляю *Privacy Policy*.

---

***Проблема заключается в следующем:***

1. Я никогда не писал политику конфиденциальности и без понятия, что
   в ней писать, как оформлять и прочее.
2. Необходимо выложить `URL`. У меня нет своего сайта или блога. Можно ли использовать `README` файл на **GitHub** или можно сделать это как-то проще?
3. А также необходимо добавить в приложение. Куда именно ее нужно
   добавить? При первом запуске приложения? Где-нибудь в настройках или
   в разделе "О приложении"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Если никогда не писали политику конфиденциальности, то можете воспользоваться таким **бесплатным** инструментом, как [Privacy Policy Generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/).

> Данный генератор учитывает такие сервисы, как **Google Play Services,
>   AdMob, Fabric, Crashlytics, Firebase Analytics** и прочие.

---

Вы можете залить политику в отдельный репозиторий, а именно в `README.md` на **GitHub**. А также на основе этого файла дополнительно создать статический сайт в настройках репозитория, используя [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/), но это не обязательно.

> Главное, чтобы было возможным указать `URL` на политику.

---

1. После всего, указать ссылку на политику конфиденциальности в **Google Console**.
2. Создать раздел *"О приложении"* и добавить ссылку. Также, если у Вас есть регистрация в приложении, то необходимо сначала дать возможность ознакомиться с политикой, т.е. указать ссылку под кнопкой регистрация.